# Creating a list of quosures using purrr

Tags: r, purrr, tidyeval

Is it possible to return a list of quosures using purrr?

```
foo <- c(1:3)
purrr::map(foo, rlang::quo(. + 2))
```

Returns the evaluated quosures (ie. a list containing 3 to 5).

Is there a way to return a list containing quo(1 + 2), quo (2 + 2) etc.?

(Package versions if significant or this is visited in the future: purrr  0.2.5, rlang 0.2.1).

Comment: maybe `purrr::map(foo, ~substitute(rlang::quo(. + 2)))` ?

Comment: That seems to return:> purrr::map(foo, ~substitute(rlang::quo(. + 2)))
[[1]]
rlang::quo(..1 + 2)

[[2]]
rlang::quo(..1 + 2)

[[3]]
rlang::quo(..1 + 2)

Comment: See section "Map-reduce to generate code" in https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html

Comment: Fab - thank you. I take it that's a new chapter in Advanced R? The 1st edition is my R bible but I tend to use it in its dead tree edition.

Comment: Just had a scout through that chapter - excellent. Exactly what I need (for this and a couple of other problems - WAY too much tidyeval going on in my project!!!)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `!!` to unquote the input into a quosure:

```r
foo <- c(1:3)
purrr::map(foo, ~ rlang::quo(!!.x + 2))
#> [[1]]
#> <quosure>
#>   expr: ^1L + 2
#>   env:  0000000015213C98
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <quosure>
#>   expr: ^2L + 2
#>   env:  0000000015217758
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> <quosure>
#>   expr: ^3L + 2
#>   env:  00000000157B9FD0
```

Note that here we also use the formula shorthand for an anonymous function in `map()` to return an unevaluated quosure. Quosures themselves can be coerced into functions by `map()` (using `purrr::as_mapper()`), so the reason why you were getting evaluated answers in the first place because you were essentially writing `map(foo, ~ . + 2)`.

Created on 2018-08-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).